# Expanded camera view in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

the camera view which i had used in my application is not same as native camera , for example,the native camera view is shown below ,
[image]

but the view is not as same in my application , i use surfaceview for my custom camera with Media recorder to capture video,in layout i use frame layout ,

```
<com.cdr.Vio.CamcorderView android:id="@+id/camcorder_preview" android:clickable="true" android:focusable="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></com.cdr.Vio.CamcorderView>
```

....

```
<Button android:id="@+id/widget34" android:background="@drawable/camrecord"
    android:layout_height="60dp" android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right" android:layout_marginRight="20dp">
</Button>
<Button android:id="@+id/widget33" android:background="@drawable/stoprecord"
    android:layout_gravity="right" android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_width="60dp" android:layout_marginTop="-60dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">
</Button>
```

i tried the view with predefined screen height and width of screen , but it again seems some  what stretched , here is my stretched camera view,
[image]

how can i resolve that , if any know that problem help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the code to record high quality video in android 2.1 by setting videEncodingBitRate , AudioEncodingBitRate, AudioSamplingRate ...etc. Using this method you can set the properties for video whatever you want to provide high quality video.

For setting high quality and low quality parameter refer this page,

http://www.andgps.com/20110410/camcorderprofile-predefined-camcorder-profile-settings-for-camcorder-applications

The code i used with base version android 2.1 to produce high quality video is shown below.

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
Method[] methods = recorder.getClass().getMethods();

recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setVideoFrameRate(24);
recorder.setVideoSize(720, 480);

for (Method method : methods) {
    try {
        if (method.getName().equals("setAudioChannels")) {
            method.invoke(recorder, String.format("audio-param-number-of-channels=%d", 1));
        } else if (method.getName().equals("setAudioEncodingBitRate")) {
            method.invoke(recorder, 12200);
        } else if (method.getName().equals("setVideoEncodingBitRate")) {
            method.invoke(recorder, 3000000);
        } else if (method.getName().equals("setAudioSamplingRate")) {
            method.invoke(recorder, 8000);
        } else if (method.getName().equals("setVideoFrameRate")) {
            method.invoke(recorder, 24);
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the aspect ratio is gone for a toss. 
Try changing the preivew resolution of the camera.

Call `setPreviewSize` on the camera parameter and set the camera parameter on the camera device. Restart the preview.

Edit: Added code

```
mCameraDevPara.setPreviewSize(PREVIEW_WIDTH, PREVIEW_HEIGHT);
mCameraDev.setParameters(mCameraDevPara);
mMediaRecoder.setCamera(mCameraDev);
```

`PREVIEW_WIDTH` and `PREVIEW_HEIGHT` should the width and the height of the preview resolution that you want to set.

Comment: how to set the Preview size for MediaRecorder

Comment: You need to set the preview size on the `Camera` object and then pass the camera object to the `MediaRecorder` via the `setCamera` method. To put it simply you set the preview resolution with respect to a particular camera object and then pass that camera object to the mediarecorder. Also ensure that the surface view that you define in your xml has the same width and height as the preview resolution.

Comment: I have added the code, try with a standard resolution first like VGA [640x480], this should maintain the aspect ratio, but it might not fill the screen of the device, if the device screen is bigger than VGA. Hope it helps.

Comment: i added as you said but when start recording recorder.start() , it shows following error                                             06-15 16:20:49.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10837): java.lang.IllegalStateException
06-15 16:20:49.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10837):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)

Comment: weird, can you use the size returned by `getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo`. Also set the preview size with the same aspect ratio as the video size that you want to record.